# Singular Value Decomposition: Nonsquare matrix, third column of U

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook says the singular value decomposition of the below matrix:

$A = \left( \begin{matrix} -2&1\\ 1&2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right)$

is given by:

$A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0&1&0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt{10}&0\\0&\sqrt{5}\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\-\frac{2}{5}&1\end{matrix}\right)=U\Sigma V^T$

However, I don't see how to get the third column of U, not only because A only yields 2 singular values, but also because the third column is multiplied out anyway. How did my textbook come up with this result?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplied out, anyway"?

Comment: If you take the product of sigma and v^T, then you get a matrix that has zeros in the bottom row. Take the product of U and that matrix, and you see that every value in U's third column is multiplied by zero.

Comment: The $\Sigma$ and $A$ have the same dimensions in the SVD. Hence $U$ needs the '3rd column'. In this example, the third column need only be orthogonal to the other two (and of unit norm, of course). Of course, this doesn't leave many options...

Comment: I suspect they just chose an arbitrary (but valid) 3rd column, as you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are some typos in $V^T$, the result should be:

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0&1&0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt{10}&0\\0&\sqrt{5}\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\\-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\end{matrix}\right)=U\Sigma V^T$$

If we need to step through the process, please give a yell.